# Distributed file source

Tags: storage, distributed, nfs, mogilefs

Looking for a software solution to to store large files (>50MB - 1.5GB), distributed across multiple servers.  We have looked at MogileFS, however, given existing software demands, need to have an NFS interface.  Would prefer open source, however, open to all options.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only a small number of servers, you could try [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/). Couple it with SSH for some security.

Answer (score 0):

did you look at Hadoop DFS?
it's much more then distributed file system but should be good for very big files.